# Prove determinant is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If

$M = \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & a & b+c \\
        1 & b & a+c \\
        1 & c & a+b \\
        \end{vmatrix}$

Show that M = 0 WITHOUT expanding the determinant.

I have tried row operations and haven't had much success.  Any tips?

Comment: Add to the third column the _______?

Comment: I feel like I should add the second column to the third but I don't know what that does for me

\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & a & a+b+c \\
        1 & b & a+b+c \\
        1 & c & a+b+c \\
        \end{vmatrix}$

Comment: What did you get from row operations? Subtracting the first row from each of the other 2 rows is the first thing I would guess, and that leaves the last 2 rows linearly dependent.

Comment: How can you tell whether a column vector is a multiple of the first column?

Comment: Then take a look at the first and third column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Add the second column to the third, and use the fact that if the columns of a matrix are linearly dependent, then the matrix has determinant zero.

Comment: Yes, I know that if the columns are linearly dependent, the determinant is zero.  Problem is, I don't see how any of them are dependent on each other.

Comment: Oh because you can multiply the first column by a+b+c and get the third?

Comment: Precisely. This shows that $(a+b+c) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} b + c \\ a + c \\ a + b \end{bmatrix} = 0$, so the columns are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the second column to the third one, the resulting column is a multiple of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

sum all columns to the right and then factored

Comment: pablocn_, it seems that your answer in not clear enough: people are flagging it as being not an answer. Can you expand on what you mean? (For example, personally, I have no idea what you mean!)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&a&b+c\\
1&b&a+c\\
1&c&a+b\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-R_1\,,\,\,R_3-R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{vmatrix}1&a&b+c\\
0&b-a&a-b\\
0&c-a&a-c\end{vmatrix}= $$

$${}$$

$$=(a-b)(a-c)\begin{vmatrix}1&a&b+c\\
0&-1&1\\
0&-1&1\end{vmatrix}$$

and clearly we reached two equal rows

Comment: This is amazingly and needlessly complicated :-)

Comment: "Amazingly" complicated? Gee, that is an "amazingly" exaggerated and odd comment. For a moment I thought I was doing calculations with the group law of an elliptic curve... Anyway, the job is done as the determinant wasn't expanded and it follows the OP's idea expressed in his question.